# Is this a pbcopy command garbled bug?

Tags: shell, markdown, stdout, manpage, pbcopy

Is this a `pbcopy` command garbled bug?
If so, is there a way to fix it?

I've tried a few ways but still can't found why this is happened.

### error / bug

> Steps to reproduce

```bash
# 1. copy output
$ man grep | pbcopy

# 2. paste to a markdown file

# 3. view the markdown file
```

[image]

using `vscode` open the `markdown` file, still garbled

[image]

### template solutions

1. output to a markdown file

```bash
# stdout
$ man ls > man-ls.md
# $ man grep > man-grep.md

# no pagination problem ✅
$ cat man-ls.md
# $ cat man-grep.md
```

[image]

2. manually copy & paste (page by page )

```bash
# copy man docs, page by page
$ man grep
```

[image]

Comment: No, `grep` doesn't detect if it's writing to a terminal, file, or pipe. The characters you see in the file are ASCII backspace characters, which pagers recognize as a form of overstriking. (N, backspace, N on a typewriter would type an N over an existing N, making it darker, so a pager will recognize it as a signal to display that text in boldface.)

Comment: vscode toggle UTF-8/UTF-16 both not work at all?

(screenshot gif) https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/Linux/unicode-garbled-bug.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `vscode` solution ✅

> use `vscode` to fix copy from the terminal encoding bug

### steps

1. export one `.md` markdown file

```bash
# export
$ man shutdown > shutdown.md
# $ man grep > grep.md
```

2. open exported `.md` file with vscode
3. select all `"` symbols， and press the `backspace`/`back delete` key twice ()

That's all.

### `gif` demo

[image]